# .Net Billing software writes to .pdf?

Tags: .net, pdf

i've never really made a "Usefull" piece of software. but now my friend asked me to create one for him. it really just goes to make it easier for him to send out he's bills. so fra i got this piece of code to work around for me editing an RTF file, however i wanna use PDF and perhabs my code is messy and not reliable? also it's coded so that it will edit an existing file i manually created. a little help on how to perhabs make it create a new .pdf file as a document would also be apreciated, however... i am very unskilled in all this. spent 2 days getting the code together i have now. what ever have a look :) So i was not sharp enough to define my question it seems...

TLDR:
i wanna ask. "How do i make it Edit PDF instead of RTF" and also "How do i make my software create a new pdf instead of editing an existing file"

```
Public Class Form2
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\game\test3.rtf"

    If System.IO.File.Exists(FILE_NAME) = True Then

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

        objWriter.Write(TextBox1.Text)
        objWriter.Close()
        MessageBox.Show("Din Faktura er nu oprettet.")

    Else

        MessageBox.Show("Faktura blev Korrupt Error : 101")

    End If
    If CheckBox1.Checked Then


        Dim i As Integer
        Dim aryText(16) As String

        aryText(0) = "Ordrenummer"
        aryText(1) = (TextBox1.Text)
        aryText(2) = "________________________________________________________________"
        aryText(3) = ""
        aryText(4) = ""
        aryText(5) = "Service Type"
        aryText(6) = (TextBox2.Text)
        aryText(7) = ""
        aryText(8) = "Service Beskrivelse"
        aryText(9) = (TextBox3.Text)
        aryText(10) = "________________________________________________________________"
        aryText(11) = ""
        aryText(12) = ""
        aryText(13) = "Pris"
        aryText(14) = (TextBox4.Text)
        aryText(15) = "________________________________________________________________"
        aryText(16) = "KuzcoSoft Alpha 0.0.0.1"

        Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

        For i = 0 To 16

            objWriter.WriteLine(aryText(i))

        Next

        objWriter.Close()
    Else
        MsgBox(" FEJL : Faktura oprettelse ikke tilladt")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can take a look at PDFSharp or iTextSharp for creating Pdf documents. Also, Your question is not very clear. What is that you want to ask.

Comment: i wanna ask. "How do i make it Edit PDF instead of RTF" and also "How do i make my software create a new pdf instead of editing an existing file" while i looked up on PDFSharp n itextSharp i believe it's a little too advanced for me. but perhabs this software i've started is a little too advanced for me?

Comment: *Creating* a pdf with a pdf library like the ones @Shakti mentioned is not so *"advanced"*, simply look at the `HelloWorld` examples and add paragraphs with your `aryText` contents instead of the single "Hello World!" paragraph. *Editing* pdfs is a bit more advanced, though, as pdf is not designed as an intermediary format but as a final format as far as its content is concerned.

Comment: oh that actually makes sense thanks @mkl so from what i hear you tell me there, i see the oportunity to keep things edited in text format. then perhabs i "just" make it convert to pdf after document have been setup. would it be harder to implement the conversion?

Comment: Well, if you immediately use a PDF library, you usually have a much more fine-grained control over the final layout. For a first proof-of-concept it may suffice, though.